# IndexOutOfRangeException on Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

Basically, I have some gridviews and then the user is expected to be able to select and delete something from within the gridview. Thing is that I cannot select or delete anything from there, I can just insert. Everytime I get this error. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it. I have a faint idea that I need to place some error treatment, but I don't know how.

Edit:

I think these are the parts that are giving me trouble:

```
 protected void grvFornecedores_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        Fornecedores objFornecedor = new Fornecedores();
        objFornecedor.fornecedorID = Convert.ToInt32(grvFornecedores.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        if (objFornecedor.Excluir())
        {
            CarregarFornecedoresGridView();
        }

    }
    protected void grvFornecedores_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        Fornecedores objFornecedor = new Fornecedores();
        objFornecedor.fornecedorID = Convert.ToInt32(
            grvFornecedores.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value
        );
        objFornecedor = objFornecedor.ListarUm();
        txtCodigoForn.Text = objFornecedor.fornecedorID.ToString();
        txtNomeFantasia.Text = objFornecedor.nomeFantasia;
        txtRazaoSocial.Text = objFornecedor.razaoSocial;
        txtCNPJ.Text = objFornecedor.cnpj.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: oh my god is this spanish? :/

Comment: It's Portuguese. My native language. @OP: please isolate the code that's giving you trouble and post here, not in another site. Also when you do bring it here please translate any useful comments.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was in a hurry and posted it without paying attention. I'm going to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should post your code here, not in other sites.

The offending code for deletion is this:

```
objFornecedor.fornecedorID = Convert.ToInt32(grvFornecedores.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
```

Instead of `e.RowIndex`, try `grvFornecedores.SelectedIndex`.